# Alternative to cartridge heater for 10mm deep hole?

Tags: resistors

I am designing my own version of a heater block for a 3D printer hot end. I had originally intended to use a 40W cartridge heater but the shortest length available I can find is 20mm and the geometry of the block only allows for a 10mm deep hole.

The heater cartridge is to be used in conjunction with a thermistor using PID control to maintain a constant temperature (approx. 200°C). Both of these elements being encased in the same aluminium block.

Is there an alternative I could use to a heater cartridge which would fit these requirements? I am unsure if a resistor could withstand this?

Comment: there's high-power resistors designed for much higher temperatures – in fact, every toaster has multiple of these.

Comment: Could try a length of nichrome wire. Thicker and shorter = more power/heat. If you have a vape shop nearby, they likely sell a rather robust version of this wire.

Comment: The limitation is the risk of  burning interior plastic next to the heater due to the heat density and poor heat spreading of the plastic.  Also there is not need for a PID control unless the dT/dt is more than 1'C/microsecond  ;) highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon a Scope soldering iron heater element might be a fit.

The heater element is carbon slug set into a copper stud at one end (the other end contactsthe soldering iron tip). It runs at about 4V and 25A at full power.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be able to find a link to one online would you? Or an image of one? (not necessarily to buy just for reference) I've had a search around based on your suggestion and can't quite find a match. Cheers